# MySQL SSL replication error - Error_code: 2026

Tags: mysql, ssl, replication

Master MySql version - **5.6.24-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log MySQL Enterprise Server**

Slave MySql version - **5.7.15-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log MySQL Enterprise Server**

**SSL replication enabled between the nodes:-** 
Master SSL config - my.cnf

```
ssl-ca=/data/mysql_data/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/data/mysql_data/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/data/mysql_data/server-key.pem
```

**Slave - config**

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='ip_address_host', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000013', MASTER_LOG_POS= 507,MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_SSL=1 , MASTER_SSL_CA='/data/server-cert.pem' , MASTER_SSL_CIPHER=' DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA'
```

**Seeing following error in the slave logs -**

> 2017-10-02T17:33:37.348979Z 1 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl@10.10.*.*:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2026

Answer (score 0):

When we downgraded the slave to same version as 5.6, it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with identical MySQL versions. It happened after an upgrade to 5.7.41.

All self-made certificates were disabled in my.cnf (by the upgrade).

Normal connection with `mysql -u my-replication-user -p -h my-awesome-server --ssl` worked as expected, but replication slave still could not connect.

I pinpointed it to the actual usage of our old certificates. And they were still used in the master configuration. So, I solved it by deleting the originally given file names of the SSL certificates.

```
change MASTER to MASTER_SSL_CA = '', MASTER_SSL_CERT = '', MASTER_SSL_KEY = ''
```